# Finding a geometric sequence where the increase is not a constant term

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need a bit of help on a geomtric sequence problem. A barn contains 50 tonnes of hay. During the first week, the farmer removes 840kg of hay from the bard. In each subsequent week, she removes from the barn 96kg hay more than she removed the previous week. Work out how much hay is left in the barn after 24 weeks.

Now i know I need to come up with a geometric sequence to solve this but I'm struggling with finding the ratio. normally i'd do this by n-(n-1). but in this case each term doesn't decrease by a constant ratio.

in week 1 she removes 840kg to leave 41960kg of hay in the barn. week 2 she takes away 840kg+96kg and week 3 its 840kg+96kg+96kg and so forth. How do i go about formulating a sequence as I am used to finding sequence where each term increases/decreases by a constant. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: yes, you are right, this is quite simply not a geometric sequence.

Comment: The terms increase by a constant _amount_, rather than by a constant factor, and sequences like that are called arithmetic instead of geometric. Also, $50\,000 - 840 = 49\,160$, not $41\,960$.

Comment: It's not a geometric sequence you're looking for but an arithmetic sequence. That is, the amount she takes away forms an arithmetic sequence. But the amount of hay in the barn at any point in time does not follow a geometric or arithmetic law.

Comment: The total amount removed on weeks $1$ to $n$, inclusive, will turn out to be quadratic in $n$.

Comment: ah right I see why I was constantly hitting a dead end then i've been looking at the wrong thing. thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is an arithmetic sequence.

Hopefully this can get you started:

In this case, during week $k$ she will remove $H(k) = H(k-1) + 96$ and we have that $H(1) = 840$

We are interested in $50,000 - \sum_{k=1}^{24} H(k)$ bales of hay left after the 24 weeks.
 Notice the following: 
$$H(3) = H(2) + 96 = (H(1) + 96) + 96 = H(1) + 2*96 = 840 + 2\times96$$

In general, $H(k) = 96(k-1) + 840$. This can be seen because
$$H(k+1) = 96(k) + 840 = 96(k-1+1) + 840 = 96(k-1) + 840 + 96= H(k) +96$$

We are then interested in $$50,000 - \sum_{k = 1}^{24}[96(k-1) + 840] = 50,000 - (24)(840) - 96\sum_{l=1}^{23}l$$. Where $l = k-1$

Comment: It seems I was going about it completely wrong from the start but that's a great help and now I know its an arithmetic sequence as well i should be ok. Thank you for the detailed walk through it was very helpful